# How to split the list of number into sub list which depend on range

Tags: python, python-3.6

I just curious is there a way to split the list of number using it own range?
Example:

```
original_list = [[0,3],[5,7]]
```

to

```
splited_list = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[5,6],[6,7]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
original_list = [[0,3],[5,7]]
splitted_list = []

for rangeDef in original_list: ## for each range definition
    for i in range(rangeDef[0], rangeDef[1]): ## for each pair of numbers within that range
        splittedList.append([i, i + 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple and short approach (with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)):

```
orig_list = [[0,3],[5,7]]
res = [[i, i+1] for a, b in orig_list for i in range(a, b)]
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [5, 6], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: You can also unpack the range bounds like this: `[[i, i+1] for a, b in orig_list for i in range(a, b)]`. Or make it golfier with `[[i, i+1] for r in orig_list for i in range(*r)]`

Comment: @Norrius, yes, let's do it

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
l = [[0,3],[5,7]]
new_l = [[a, b] for c, d in l for a, b in zip(range(c, d+1), range(c, d+1)[1:])]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [5, 6], [6, 7]]
```